# Integrability of powers of functions imply the integrability of their product

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I am stuck on this.

Let $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space satisfying $\mu(X)<\infty$ and let $f, g, h: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable functions such that $f^{4}, g^{4}$ and $h^{3}$ are Lebesgue integrable. Must $f g h$ be Lebesgue integrable? Justify your answer.

I had the idea to prove that the absolute value of fgh is integrable using the Holder integral (I separated fg from h by using p=4 and q=4/3 but I got stuck with the integrale of a power of h).

Any hint or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I meant to say Holder inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mu (X)<\infty$ we have inclusion $L^p (\mu )\subset L^s (\mu )$ for $p>s. $So we have $f,g\in L^4 (\mu )$ hence $f,g\in L^3  (\mu )$ and thus $f,g,h\in L^3 (\mu ) $ but this implies that $fgh\in L^1 (\mu )$ thus the function $fgh$ is integrable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know how that slipped by me (the proof of it has the Holder inequality too that I was trying to use in such a complicated way).